# Thin white border on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, mobile

I'm having an issue with a thin white border displaying at the bottom of my site just after the footer on iPhone only.

I'm using an iPhone 5 with iOS8 and I've also tested on a 4S with iOS7 and had the same issue. I've tested various Android Devices, and they are all fine.

I can't find anything in my CSS that would be causing this issue. I've tried the negative margin method but that did not work. If anyone else has run into this problem, I could really use some insight on what could be causing it. Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's the [link](http://jtwebfolio.com/newsite)

It might be hard to see it on a white background, but here is a screenshot.

[image: Might be hard to see on a white background...]

Comment: Can you please tell us the browsers that give you this issue? Safari? Chrome? Firefox? I checked your website on Safari iPhone and it seems fine. I also used the iPhone emulator of Google Chrome and didn't get the thin white border issue.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that information would be useful. For me it's Safari and Chrome on iOS8. I'll post a screenshot of it in the post above.